# XCode iOS project works under 10.6, crashes under 10.7

Tags: ios, xcode, osx-lion

I have an iOS XCode project that I have been working on under 10.6 for some time. Under 10.6.8, Xcode 4.2, it builds and runs perfectly, both in the simulator and on a device.

I then attempted to move it to a 10.7 machine running the Lion version of XCode 4.2 by zipping the entire project folder (including all the resources it uses), copying it to the 10.7 machine, and unzipping it. When I then run the project under 10.7 on a device, it also works. HOWEVER, if I attempt to run the project under the iOS simulator, it now crashes on the initial UIApplicationMain call with a SIGABRT. All I can see of the error (at least where I am looking) says "Application received SIGABRT", with no indication of why. This is in the main function before any code that I have written gets executed (verified with break points).

I have checked and double checked that all the files the Xcode project is looking for exist and have proper permissions. New projects created with identical settings (as far as I can tell) to my current project run in the simulator fine. As mentioned, even my project runs fine when run on an iOS device. It is just when I try to run my project in the iOS simulator that I have problems. Does anyone have any idea how I can fix this, short of creating a new project and copying all my code in?

Comment: check your iOS targets  perhaps

Comment: also the base compiler for both of them are different... gcc and llvm-gcc.... the lion's acts a little wierd... try to clean and then debug/run.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two possibilities:

Xcode generates derived data (index files, intermediate build products, etc.). Normally that data is stored in the user's Library folder, but project settings can direct Xcode to store that data anywhere, including in the project directory. If you've moved this derived with your project, and it depended upon anything in your 10.6 system, it may be producing an executable that will not work on your Mac. Try deleting that derived data. You can use the projects tab in the Xcode Organizer to delete it, or just go digging for it with the Finder and trash the folders.

Another possibility is that the scheme created for this project may be trying to run the app on a version of the iOS simulator not installed on the new Mac. Try creating a new scheme on the new Mac. Xcode should create the new scheme with default settings that are appropriate for that configuration of Xcode.